# Why is postfix not allowing received mail from internet?

Tags: postfix

I have a mail setup where a public mail server (`mail.domain.com`) receives mail to `domain.com` and relays that mail to an internal server (`mail.domain.local`) at `domainlocal2.com` and am having an issue where the internal server isn't allowing the email to come through. I know the external server is functioning because it works with another domain just fine.

Works: If I send mail internally, all through the internal server `mail.domain.local` to `myuser@domainlocal2.com`, the recipient receives the mail just fine.

Doesn't work: If mail comes in to `mail.domain.com` for `aaa@domain.com` which relays internally to `mail.domain.local` for `myuser@domainlocal2.com`, it is rejected by `mail.domain.local`.

Any ideas?

main.cf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no

# SPF policy settings
policyd-spf_time_limit = 3600
myhostname = mail.domain.local
mydomain = domain.local

# Basic configuration
alias_maps = texthash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = texthash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain domainlocal2.com
relayhost = [sshtunnel]:8000
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64 172.18.0.0/16 23.AAA.14.77/32
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/cert
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/ssl/key
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
tls_high_cipherlist=ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
smtpd_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols=!SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, LOW, EXP, MEDIUM, ADH, AECDH, MD5, DSS, ECDSA, CAMELLIA128, 3DES, CAMELLIA256, RSA+AES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs

# Settings to prevent SPAM early
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, permit
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain

# SASL
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes

# Mail directory
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/dovecot/lmtp
virtual_mailbox_domains = domain.local domainlocal.com domainlocal2.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-groups.cf

# Additional option for filtering
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024

# Milters used by DKIM
milter_protocol = 6
milter_default_action = accept
dkim_milter = inet:localhost:8891
dmarc_milter = inet:localhost:8893
smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter,$dmarc_milter
non_smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter

debug_peer_list = 127.0.0.1, mail.domain.com, mail.domain.local
```

Postfix output: https://pastebin.com/raw/WqrC550U

As a note, this error:

```
warning: do not list domain domainlocal2.com in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
```

.. was from a test, but doesn't effect any other outputs when it's there or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be relaying into 587 instead of 25 for anyone else who runs into this.

Comment: Nobody could see this error, because you didn't show your `master.cf`.